# Replace character in a string in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How can I replace two characters, 5th and 6th digit in the string below?

```
 2xxx99xx
```

I want to replace 5th and 6th digit (which is 99) by getting the record count of the file.

```
 $cat file | wc -l
 3
```

The output must be:

```
 2xxx03xx
```

Comment: Could possibly be done with [`sed`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html), or [`awk`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gawk.1.html), or many other programs. You might want to try yourself first, and tell us *what* you tried and how it went.

Comment: `wc -l < file` is preferable to `cat file | wc -l`.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, i tried this **record_count=`wc -l < $FILE` FOO=2xxx03xx awk -v rec="${record_count}" ' { data  = substr ($0, 5, 6); data=rec; print }'** but nothing changes with FOO. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Where is the string `2xxx99xx` stored? In a variable? In a file? Piped from some other command? Do you want the original file or variable to be modified or do you just want to see the updated string in stdout? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

```
foo=2xxx99xx
printf "%s%02d%s" ${foo:0:4} $(wc -l < file) ${foo:6}
```

Comment: I got this error ${trailer:0:4}: The specified substitution is not valid for this command. Please note that **trailer=$(tail -n 1 $FILES)**

Comment: What does `tail -n 1 $FILES` print for you?

Comment: This is the printed output: 20019923

Comment: Works perfectly for me.  Maybe if you post your entire script that doesn't work...otherwise it seems like there's something wrong in a piece you aren't showing us.

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
echo "2xxx99xx" | sed -r "s/(.{4})..(.*)/\1$(printf "%02d" `wc -l < ff`)\2/g"
```

first 4 characters form group 1, rest of the string except 5th and 6th characters form group 2. Then we put back the 1st group, formatted data, then the 2nd group.

If the sed version doesn't support extended regex, use below command:

```
echo "2xxx99xx" | sed "s/\(.\{4\}\)..\(.*\)/\1$(printf "%02d" `wc -l < ff`)\2/g"
```

Comment: How if I got a 4-digit record count. For example, I got **4567** record count, how can I get **2x4567xx**?

Comment: what are the other possiblities? if u have 45678, do u need output to be 245678xx?. if u have 456789, do u need output to be 456789xx?

Comment: Yes exactly, it should replace preceding digits.

Comment: Yes exactly, it should replace preceding digits